# Change default selection color for QTableView

Tags: qt, qtableview, qabstracttablemodel

I am using a QTableView with QAbstractTableModel.

I have subclassed `QAbstractTableModel` and in my model class for `Qt::BackgroundRole` and `Qt::ForegroundRole` I have returned some color depending on some condition.

And I have subclassed `QTableView` class.

When I select any row/cell on the table, the row/cell is highlighted in the default color of the tabelVeiw, **it does not show the color returned from  my model class**.

How can I change this behavior? How can I avoid/ignore this default coloring of `QTableView` and have only the colors returned by my model class?

Comment: Any code samples? And why you need to subclass `QTableView`?

Comment: I subclassed `QTableView` because in my case the table will react to left click, double click, and right click. Without subclassing, with the given signal slots if I implement  `QWidget::customContextMenuRequested` and `QAbstractItemView::clicked` then if I right click it emits the click() signal as well. That is why I had to subclass QTableView and re-implement `mousePressEvent` to differentiate left and right mouse click

Comment: You should use `QItemDelegate` to handle mouse events.

Comment: Can you please take the time to elaborate please? :) I want only the QColor/QBrush that is returned from my model class to represent my TableView cells and nothing else. How can I do this? Your elaborate answer will be much appreciated :)

Comment: Stackoverflow is not designed for free code writing. Once again - you need to clarify your question and provide an SSCCE. You may start with Qt documentation and ask extra questions if something will not be clear.

Comment: you are right, had a tight time schedule and my brain wasn't working(still not working)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a custom *delegate*.
Subclass the `QStyledItemDelegate` and implement it's `paint()` method like this:

```
void MyDelegate::paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex & index) const
{
    QStyleOptionViewItem itemOption(option);              
    initStyleOption(&itemOption, index); 

    if ((itemOption.state & QStyle::State_Selected) &&
        (itemOption.state & QStyle::State_Active))
        itemOption.palette.setColor(QPalette::Highlight, Qt::red);  // set your color here

    QApplication::style()->drawControl(QStyle::CE_ItemViewItem, &itemOption, painter, nullptr);
}
```

If you want to get yout selecion color from the model, I suggest to define a special custom role for that purpose:

```
enum MyRoles
{
    HighlightColorRole = Qt::UserRole
};
```

Your model will use this role to return your custom highlight (selection) color through the `QAbstractItemModel::data()` method.

In your delegate you can obtain that color like this:

```
QColor color = index.data(HighlightColorRole).value<QColor>();
```

Comment: Here we are setting the row color to red `itemOption.palette.setColor(QPalette::Highlight, Qt::red);` but the color of my selected row/rows is determined in my Model class depending on some condition. What should I do if I want only the color that is returned form the model and nothing else?

Comment: Thanks, hopefully this will do the trick :D Currently I am trying out your solution, but `initStyleOption(&itemOption, index);` throws a error saying " 'initStyleOption': identifier not found ". Seems like function belongs to `QStyledItemDelegate` http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstyleditemdelegate.html#initStyleOption . Any idea?

Comment: For some reason the pain function is not called.

Here is my custom delegate class

header file
http://ideone.com/6xS5uK

Source file
http://ideone.com/Hdbjtk

And I set the delegate to my View class like this
`myTableView->setItemDelegate(mCustomDelegateClass);`

What have I done wrong :/

Comment: Yeah, you are right, the `initStyleOption()` method is not part of the `QItemDelegate`, so derive your custom delegate from the `QStyledItemDelegate`. And your `paint()` method is not called because in your derived delegate it's not defined as a **const** method.

Comment: I have corrected my answer. So put that **const** modifier behind your `paint()` method declaration and it will be fine.

Comment: As SO suggested, let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103598/discussion-between-sami1592-and-tomas).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the the color of the QTableview when a cell is selected you can do something like this :

```
QPalette palette = tableview->palette();
    palette.setColor(QPalette::Highlight, QColor(255,255,255,100)); //set your own colors and transparency level in QColor
    tableview->setPalette(palette);
```